# Move caption image to the left

Tags: css, wordpress

I use wordpress and I have a little problem. When I use caption in the images.

The right images are always good, however, the left images don't look good at all.

Link: http://www.f1zone.net/news/renault-admits-jerez-performance-not-acceptable/24682/

We have only one class: **.wp-caption** but if we change that; the right images placement will change too.

I don't know what to do, as I have no experience in creating another class.

So how can I create a new class only for left images? I just want to move them a little bit to the left, and make a little space with the text.

P.S: The right and left images (without caption) look great, and I don't want to change that. I only want to change the left images which uses a caption.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is that the left images don't have enough space on their right, between the body text and them, then simply change your CSS to:

```
.wp-caption {
text-align: center;
background-color: #EEE;
padding-top: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-khtml-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}
.wp-caption.alignright {margin: 8px 0px 10px 10px;}
.wp-caption.alignleft {margin: 8px 10px 10px 0;}
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the delay. But this didn't work at all. Please check: http://www.f1zone.net/news/is-formula-1-ready-to-feel-the-force/26582/

Comment: I had a mistake in my answer, check again. Change the margins of .wp-caption.alignleft and .wp-caption.alignright according to your taste

Comment: Thanks a lot :) all OKay now!